# Display the date to the user in different Dateformat depending where he is from

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I got a function which converts my timestamp into a date and looks like this:

```
delivery: function(created) {
            var date = new Date(created * 1000);
            var formattedDate = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + 
            ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ,' + 
            ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);



        return formattedDate;
    }
```

now I want to display the date in MM/DD/YYYY for the american user which come to my site, so I would like to implement an if-clause, which firstly looks where the user comes from and then display the date in MM/DD/YYYY if he is from america, and if he is from europe in DD/MM/YYYY

Well in the SAPUI5 documentation I just saw this:

// The source value is given as timestamp. The used output pattern is "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm": e.g. 22.12.2010 13:15

```
oType = new sap.ui.model.type.DateTime({source: {pattern: "timestamp"}, pattern: "dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm"});
```

but I don't really understand how it works if I do oType.formatValue(created); its not working so maybe someone with more experience can explain me where I have to put my timestamp which is stored under "created"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with simply using

```
delivery: function(created) {
    var date = new Date(created * 1000);
    return date.toLocaleDateString() + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

exactly?

EDIT: For clarity, I've supplied the whole function, not just the return statement

Comment: I dont want to give back the date we have right now, I get a datetime back of an service and that is created : 1465475131 , as you can see thats a timestamp and its the timestamp from the 09.06.2016 , 14:25 , and thats what I want to do

Comment: That's what I meant; `date` in my answer is the variable you used, i.e. `var date = new Date(created * 1000)`

Comment: yes but the time is missing I want to display also the hours and minutes, is that possible too?

Comment: wow nice, so this converts the date depending on the browser language to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS for european user and for american user to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS , right?

Comment: Not on the browser language, but on the user's computer specified locale/region -- also, there are multiple ways dates can be displayed across Europe! (think DD-MM-YYYY for Dutch, DD.MM.YYYY in Germany, DD/MM/YYYY in UK, etc)

Comment: thats great thanks mate have a nice weekend that saved my day :)